# DataTables TableTools plugin - How to configure sSwfPath path in Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, datatables, tabletools

A re-post of my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15802470/datatables-tabletools-not-able-to-find-the-path-for-sswfpath) as I am not getting any satisfactory answer

The problem is as follows :

I have given my code in JSBin http://live.datatables.net/aqowib/2 for which I am not able to link to the sSwfPath properly. I am using codeiginter in my application so I am trying to load the files as follows:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="http://<?php base_url(); ?>/assets/js/jquery.dataTables.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://<?php base_url(); ?>/js/jquery.dataTables.columnFilter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://<?php base_url(); ?>/media/js/ZeroClipboard.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://<?php base_url(); ?>/media/js/TableTools.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And my script tag contains the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var oTable = $('#datatables').dataTable({
        "sPaginationType":"full_numbers",
        "sDom": 'Tlfrtip',
        "oTableTools": {
            "sSwfPath": "<?php base_url();?>/media/swf/copy_cvs_xls_pdf.swf"
        },
        "sScrollX": "100%",
        "bScrollCollapse": true,
        "bAutoWidth": true,
        "aaSorting":[[0, "asc"]],
        "bJQueryUI":true
    }).columnFilter({
        aoColumns: [ null,
                     null,
                     { type: "select", values: [ 'male', 'female']  },
                     null,
                     null,
                     null,
                     null,
                     { type: "select", values: [ '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7','8','9','10']  },
                     { type: "select", values: [ 'A', 'B', 'C']  },
                     null,
                     { type: "select", values: ['P', 'A'] },
                     null,
                     null,
                     null
            ]
    });
});
```

Everytime I am getting the 404 error saying that Unable to load SWF file - please check the SWF path

Please help me where am I wrong ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

No need to write full path 
Just place echo before base_url :) 
Change

```
<?php base_url();?>
```

To

```
<?php echo base_url();?>
```

Comment: This DOES provide an answer to the question. The author asked where he was wrong, and this is where he was wrong. It almost certainly solves his problem

Answer (score 0):

Ah, Got the solution !!

You just need to configure the sSwfPath URL in the TableTools.js file i.e.

CHANGE TableTools default settings for initialisation

Here I go :

```
TableTools.DEFAULTS = {
    "sSwfPath":         "http://localhost/codegen/media/swf/copy_cvs_xls_pdf.swf", <----------------- HERE IS WHERE I GOT STUCK 
    "sRowSelect":       "none",
    "fnPreRowSelect":   null,
    "fnRowSelected":    null,
    "fnRowDeselected":  null,
    "aButtons":         [ "copy", "csv", "xls", "pdf", "print" ]
};
```

Thanks :-)

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that your `<?php base_url();?>` is returning a wrong value?

Comment: Dear NealCaffrey, how can we use the sSwfPath in laravel 4.2 page? Please give suggestion

Comment: Although this might have solved your problem, it is not what caused the problem. You forgot to use echo and so berbt was right. The part `<?php base_url();?>` does not return a value. See the answer of Vishav B Kaith.

Comment: Additional: And it will only work if you have got your javascript code in your PHP file. If not, you have to make it avilable to your javascript files by assigning it to a global Javascript variable like this: `echo '<script type="text/javascript"> window.baseUrl = ' . base_url();` Now you can access it with window.baseUrl in your javascript files.