# Open PDF in a new tab with jQuery Datatables

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html, datatables

I'm trying to open in a new tab the PDF that it is in a collection button of jQuery Datatables but it doesn't work. Instead it shows me an alert message like this:

[image]

This is my jQuery configuration:

```
$("#clientes").DataTable({
    dom: 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
    tableTools: {
        "aButtons": [
            {
                "sExtends": "collection",
                "sButtonText": "Generar Listado <span class='caret' />",
                "aButtons": ['csv', 'xls', {
                    extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                    download: 'open'
                }]
            }
        ],
        "sSwfPath": "Content/DataTables/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
       }
    });
```

Any ideas of how I can resolve this issue with this collection button of jquery datatables?

I have put all the references inside my bundle class to tried to make it work:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems come from `"sSwfPath"` value provided incorrectly, so that the button type becomes `undefined`:

```
"sSwfPath": "Content/DataTables/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
```

The button check condition applies inside `_fnButtonDefinations` in [`dataTables.tableTools.js`](https://github.com/DataTables/TableTools/blob/master/js/dataTables.tableTools.js):

```
if (typeof TableTools.BUTTONS[ buttonSet[i] ] == 'undefined' )  { 
    alert( "TableTools: Warning - unknown button type: "+buttonSet[i]);
    continue;
}
buttonDef = $.extend({}, TableTools.BUTTONS[buttonSet[i]], true);
```

You can try `UrlHelper.Content` with relative path to SWF file or referring directly from `DataTables` CDN external resource:

```
// local content (in Razor view)
"sSwfPath": "@Url.Content("~/Content/DataTables/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf")"

// external resource (i.e. DataTables CDN)
"sSwfPath": "http://cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.2/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
```

Also you can trying to set `sExtends` to `pdf` instead of `collection`:

```
$("#clientes").DataTable({
    dom: 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
    tableTools: {
        "aButtons": [
            {
                "sExtends": "pdf",
                "sButtonText": "Generar Listado <span class='caret' />",
                "aButtons": ['csv', 'xls', {
                    extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                    download: 'open'
                }]
            }
        ],
        "sSwfPath": "http://cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.2/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
    }
});
```

Example: [JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/01Lkx8bh/)

The next issue you need to watch is file security issue due to some restrictions imposed against loading external SWF resource. Open [global security settings panel](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html) and select "Always allow" for CDN resource, or for locally stored SWF use "Add locations" (see image below), enter SWF path assigned to `sSwfPath` then confirm to apply trust for that path (may require refreshing the view afterwards).

[image: Adobe Flash Player Settings Manager]

References:

[DataTables TableTools buttons not working correctly (simple example)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23222554/datatables-tabletools-buttons-not-working-correctly-simple-example)

[TableTools export in JQuery Datatables not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29877651/tabletools-export-in-jquery-datatables-not-working)

[jQuery dataTables - TableTools not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24837595/jquery-datatables-tabletools-not-working)

[jQuery TableTools not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8442002/jquery-tabletools-not-working)